# pROC median Sensitivity vs. manual Sensitivity calculation - different Results

Tags: r, roc, confusion-matrix, proc-r-package

Calculating the **sensitivity manually** from the confusion matrix, gives the value **0.853.**

- TN = 16
- FP = 7
- FN = 5
- TP = 29

The output of pROC is different (median = 0.8235).

```
y_test = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

y_pred_prob = c(0.63069148, 0.65580015, 0.9478634 , 0.94471701, 0.24756774,
       0.51969906, 0.26881201, 0.6722361 , 0.30275069, 0.61676645,
       0.76116789, 0.90867332, 0.31525658, 0.10681422, 0.6890589 ,
       0.25185641, 0.54820684, 0.7175465 , 0.57194733, 0.71304872,
       0.98805141, 0.92829077, 0.38150015, 0.97653216, 0.96036858,
       0.75878699, 0.95466371, 0.52292342, 0.28296724, 0.5660834 ,
       0.91581461, 0.49574317, 0.79025422, 0.14303487, 0.66885536,
       0.07660444, 0.10342033, 0.53661914, 0.04701796, 0.83313871,
       0.37766607, 0.89157993, 0.47731778, 0.62640482, 0.47664294,
       0.0928437 , 0.13605622, 0.2561323 , 0.95572329, 0.49051571,
       0.49267652, 0.92600581, 0.48464618, 0.96006108, 0.01548211,
       0.56057243, 0.82257937)

set.seed(99)
boot = 2000
rocobj <- roc(y_test, y_pred_prob)
print(ci.thresholds(rocobj,.95, thresholds =  0.5, method = 'bootstrap',boot.n = boot))

OUT:    95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
     thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
      0.5002624 0.5652    0.7391   0.913 0.6765    0.8235  0.9412
```

Is this a result of the bootstrapping method? Because it is a median?

Comment: The bootstrap is a random-based method, you should expect different results. Try, for instance, to change the RNG seed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have tried to do this, but it does not change much, if at all. So I am curious how the large difference between 0.853 and  0.8235 occurs...

Comment: Mischa this is showing the sensitivity using a threshold of 0.5. If you use a threshold of 0.5 to get your manual sensitivity (e.g. `table(prediction = y_pred_prob > 0.5, actual = y_test)`), then you get a different confusion matrix from the one you have shown. That confusion matrix gives a sensitivity of 0.8235 (it's 28/34 rather than 29/34). Are you maybe using the optimum cutoff for your confusion matrix? If so, you need to pass that value to the threshold argument of `ci.thresholds`

Comment: Well done @AllanCameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What threshold did you use?

You need to be careful when you report and analyze the results of a confusion matrix. When you have numeric predictions, you must consider at which threshold this table was generated. Given the numbers in it, I will assume you used a threshold of 0.495 or something close to that, which allowed me to obtain the same numbers as you:

```
> table(y_test, y_pred_prob > 0.495)
      
y_test FALSE TRUE
     0    17    6
     1     5   29
```

## How to get the empirical sensitivity and specificity from pROC?

Now that we have a threshold to work with, we can extract the data for this threshold from pROC with the [coords](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/coords) function:

```
> coords(rocobj, 0.495, "threshold", transpose = FALSE)
  threshold specificity sensitivity
1     0.495   0.7391304   0.8529412
```

This is exactly the sensitivity you calculated.

## What about boostrapping?

As you suspected, the boostrapping that is used to calculate the confidence intervals is a stochastic process and the median of the resampled curves is going to be different from the empirical value.

However for a median with 2000 bootstrap replicates we get pretty close:

```
> set.seed(99)
> print(ci.thresholds(rocobj,.95, thresholds =  0.495, method = 'bootstrap',boot.n = boot))

95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
 thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
      0.495 0.5652    0.7391   0.913 0.7353    0.8529  0.9706
```